# Music visualisations

Tags: windows, video, music, visualization

I'm using DLNA network in my home to show PC contents on TV that support DLNA. (Don't get confused, It's not like VGA or HDMI cable. TV gets files from PC and plays them, doesn't show screen of PC)

You know, it's boring to just listen music if there is no video. I want to visualize music, but my TV doesn't support it.

I'm looking for **FREE** a way to generate [this type](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YHbfzQRwVY) (or [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtlgJ7qFjCs)) type of videos from music files, or perhaps a source from which I can download ready made ones of popular music.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Does [this link](http://alenblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/stream-computer-desktop-to-tv-using-dlna-tversity-and-vlc/) or [this one](http://alenblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/tversity-dlna-for-samsung-tv/) help?

Comment: @harrymc there is no exact way tp do it

Comment: XBMC is open source(GPL) and closs plataform: http://xbmc.org/about/

Comment: @TiagoCA this comment is far far away from my question

Comment: Quoting the web page linked by @TiagoCA: *"There are […] many audio visualizations."* [More about XMBC music playback](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Music_playback). I don't think it's "far far away from [your] question".

Comment: @DanielBeck it's PC player software. I'm looking for DLNA Server. You feel difference?

Answer (score 1):

G-Force is the best thing I've seen for generating visualizations. However, it performs in real-time so you would need to record the video and music playing, then merge it into one file. SnagIt is capable of doing this fairly simply.

[G-Force website](http://www.soundspectrum.com/g-force/)
[SnagIt website](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)

On the same note, if your simply looking for a spectrum analyzer, Windows Media player has that built in. Use the same recording method to record it with you music, then playback the video on your TV instead of just the mp3(or whatever).

Comment: OMGG:)) I need fast, free way to do it. Not to record every time something then montage it

Comment: Only way I can see doing this then would be to hook your PC to your TV. There aren't any visualization engines that would play through DLNA in the manner you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

[Wild Media Server](http://www.wildmediaserver.com) has visualizations.

Comment: Looking for free way